# Error al ejecutar dos procedimientos en Codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, stored-procedure

El problema es que en un controlador trato de ejecutar los dos procedimientos me salta este error:

> **A Database Error Occurred**
>
> Error Number: 2014
>
> Commands out of sync: you can´t run this command now
>
> CALL cargos();
>
> Filename: models/Modelo_empleados.php
>
> Line Number: 56

Mi controlador:

```
public function consulta(){
    $criterio=$this->input->post("criterio");
    $data["consulta"]=$this->Modelo_empleados->consultar($criterio);
    $data["puesto"]=$this->Modelo_empleados->cargos();
    $this->load->view("layout/header");
    $this->load->view("layout/menu");
    $this->load->view("layout/empleados",$data);
    $this->load->view("layout/footer");
}
```

El modelo:

```
public function consultar($dato){
    $con=$this->db->query("CALL consulta_empleado('$dato',@id,@nom,@ap,@am,@calle,@colonia,@localidad,@estado,@n_int,@n_ext,@cp,@tel,@email,@horario,@cargo);");
    return $con->result();
}
public function cargos(){
    $query=$this->db->query("CALL cargos();");
    return $query->result();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dejaré esta solución por acá quizas le sirva a alguien. Si estas utilizando codeigniter 3, pon este codigo en la siguiente ruta /system/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_driver.php

```
function free_db_resource()
{
    do
    {
        if($l_result = mysqli_store_result($this->conn_id))
        {
            mysqli_free_result($l_result);
        }
    }
    while(mysqli_more_results($this->conn_id)  && mysqli_next_result($this->conn_id));
}
```

luego despues de cada llamada usas el siguiente codigo:

$this->db->free_db_resource();